# Pip error generating metadata setuptools not available

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, setuptools

I'm encountering a problem when trying to install a package with both `pip install` and `python -m pip install`.

I just installed python 3.10.3 thanks to a script that replaced python2 as the default `python` on my Raspberry Pi.

Here's the error:

> Collecting python-telegram-bot
> Using cached https://www.piwheels.org/simple/python-telegram-bot/python_telegram_bot-13.11-py3-none-any.whl (498 kB)
> Collecting tornado>=6.1
> Using cached tornado-6.1.tar.gz (497 kB)
> Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
> error: subprocess-exited-with-error
>
> × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.   │ exit code:
> 1   ╰─> [1 lines of output]
> ERROR: Can not execute `setup.py` since setuptools is not available in the build environment.
> [end of output]
>
> note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a
> problem with pip. error: metadata-generation-failed
>
> × Encountered error while generating package metadata. ╰─> See above
> for output.
>
> note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
> hint: See above for details.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried adding this: `--use-deprecated=backtrack-on-build-failures`
after install statement ?

like:

```
pip install python-telegram-bot --use-deprecated=backtrack-on-build-failures
```